# Defining the least infinite limit ordinal constructively

Tags: proof-verification, logic, set-theory, ordinals, universal-algebra

**Edit:** I didn't know about the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) when I wrote this question. I'm going to leave it, though, because I find some of the comments to be helpful.

Let $(X,\sigma,\prec)$ be a structure satisfying the following:

$1.\qquad \exists o.o\in X$

$2.\qquad \forall x\in X.\sigma(x)\in X$

$3. \qquad \forall x\in X. x\prec\sigma(x)$

$4. \qquad \forall x,y \in X. x\prec y\implies x\ne y$

$5. \qquad \forall x,y,z \in X. x\prec y \land y\prec z\implies x\prec z$

Prove

$A\qquad(X,\prec)\cong(\omega,\in)$

$B\qquad\nexists\beta\in\mathbf{Ord}.((X,\prec)\cong(\beta,\in))\land(\beta\ne\omega)$

As far as I am aware (I tried coding it in MetaMath, but it didn't work) it is not possible to prove either $A$ or $B$ from $1,\ldots,5$. In fact, the extent of $X$ should be ambiguous since there is no upper bound on the set "$X$ such that $X$ is inductive" - which, as far as I can tell, is exactly the structure being described (by way of $\sigma(x)=x\cup\{x\}$).

I believe that two additional conditions would be necessary in order to prove $A$, these being:

$6.\qquad\nexists x\in X.o=\sigma(x)$

and

$7.\qquad \forall y\in X\setminus\{o\}.\exists x\in X.y=\sigma(x)$

$B$ could be proven from $A$ iff $o=\emptyset$; otherwise $B$ is consistent with $1,\ldots,7$ for $o=\lambda$, for any limit ordinal $\lambda$.

Is this correct, and if not, what additional conditions must be met in order to prove $A$ and $B$?

---

Note: I have no idea what "constructive mathematics" actually is, I'm only using the term "constructively" in the title based on what I can infer about its meaning from how others have used it. If "constructive" isn't the appropriate term to describe what I am doing, please correct it.

Comment: How about a copy of $\omega$ followed by a copy if $\mathbb Z$?  Will that not satisfy 1—7?   According to Löwenheim-Skolem, no finite set of first-order axioms can uniquely define the least infinite ordinal.

Comment: Meanwhile, $\omega$ is defined to be the set of all finite ordinals (remember that ordinals are themselves sets of ordinals). It's easy to show that $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal: just show that an infinite must contain every finite ordinal (so if $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal, we have $\omega\subseteq\alpha$ as sets, which is to say $\omega\le\alpha$ in the ordering on the ordinals).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Doesn't that make the definition of "infinite" circular?

Comment: @GEdgar You're understating the impact of Lowenheim-Skolem (really, compactness - you're using upwards Lowenheim-Skolem, and that's just the compactness theorem): no set of first-order axioms *at all* can characterize $(\omega,<)$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: @R.Burton It depends what definitions you're starting with. For example, one might define a finite ordinal to be one which is contained in every inductive set of ordinals. The class of finite ordinals can then be proved to be a set, and it's this set which we call $\omega$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber set of finite ordinals -def-> contained in every inductive set. in every inductive set -def-> in intersection of inductive sets. intersection of inductive sets -def-> set of finite ordinals -> ...?

Comment: Another approach would be to call an ordinal finite if every ordinal less than it is either $0$ or a successor ordinal. Then, again, we can show that there is a set of all finite ordinals and that every infinite ordinal contains this ordinal as a subset, and this is what we call $\omega$.

Comment: @R.Burton Where's the circularity there? The definition of "inductive set" **doesn't** make use of the notion of finite: $X$ is inductive iff (i) every element of $X$ is an ordinal, (ii) whenever $a\in X$ and $b\in a$ we have $b\in X$, (iii) $\emptyset\in X$, and (iv) whenever $a\in X$ we have $a\cup\{a\}\in X$. There's no circularity here. (Actually (i) and (ii) are unnecessary for our purposes, but meh.)

Comment: @R.Burton No, why would it? I've explicitly given a definition of inductive set which **does not** involve finiteness, and then defined finiteness in terms of inductive sets. On this approach (there are others which are also non-circular and ultimately amount to the same thing) inductiveness is defined first and finiteness is defined subsequently. Where's the circularity?

Comment: The definition of "inductive" is fine, its the definition of "finite" I'm worried about.

Comment: @R.Burton But I've defined finiteness in terms of inductiveness, with no circularity: $\alpha$ is a finite ordinal iff $\alpha$ is in every inductive set. **Where is the perceived circularity?** At what point have I used the word being defined in the definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97438/discussion-between-r-burton-and-noah-schweber).